# Gamesalad actor image mask with wiping mouse input

Tags: image, multi-touch, masking

I've tried searching for 'actor mask with gamesalad', 'actor image mask with game salad', and 'image mask with gamesalad', but can't seem to even find the fundamentals for creating a mask on game salad.

Basically, I would like my final result to look like something splats on the screen, and then the player wipes it off with their finger which is where the mask part comes in.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking but I think i know what you're getting at. Do you mean that you want to erase the part of a picture where a users finger has been? Abit like some sort of finger eraser tool?

If so I hate to say that Gamesalad doesn't do this at the moment. I had a quick play to see if it could be done with image modes but didn't have any luck. The only way I could think that you could do it is by having a solid colour background (which may not be in favour of you app design) and then spawning a 1x1pixel sized actor every 0.01 second when the touch is pressed on location of the finger. This would create the illusion that an item is being erased.

Hope that helps.